# jetty-7: Disable login for special connector

Tags: jetty, embedded-jetty

i'm using an embedded jetty 7 server with a HTTP and a HTTPS connector. Both connectors using the IP address as host. The server is using a HashLoginService. That works fine so far.

Now i got an additional requirement: I have to disable the hash login when the the server is called on localhost. So i added a third connector bound to localhost, but i did not manage to disable the login service for that connector. The HashLoginService is added as bean on Server context.

Any hints for me? Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: [Jetty 7 is EOL (End of Life)](https://dev.eclipse.org/mhonarc/lists/jetty-announce/msg00069.html), consider upgrading.

Comment: I know that, thank you. Version 7 is required because of a Java 1.5 VM in the host system. Are there any differences regarding my requirement in Jetty 9?

Comment: There's been literally hundreds of releases (and tens of thousands of commits) since Jetty 7, the [amount of change since then](https://abi-laboratory.pro/java/tracker/timeline/jetty/) is staggering.  So regardless of the topic, yes, there are differences in your requirement in Jetty 9 (vs Jetty 7)

Comment: Yeah, i see. However, upgrading is not an option. Maybe my original question leads to the wrong direction. Is there a way to log in a HttpSession programmatically?

Comment: Java 1.5 is also EOL/Expired.  You know that on Jan 1, 2017 existing browsers will likely be unable to connect to your HTTPS connector, right? (The global SHA1 deprecation day)  When you use SSL/TLS you have to stay up to date with the JVM at a bare minimum.